# ~/.ssh/rc Auto Login to seperate shell

Tags: bash, ssh, administrator, rc

Below is the codeblock which I use within my RC file. The idea is to move straight into another servers ssh session (without port forwarding). When this executes, I see the session. This said, it blinks rapidly and is not interactive. I believe this is by design, but, is there another way to call on the ssh command after a specific user logs in? If not, do you know a workaround to make the screen interactive? Thank you.

```
if [ ! -z "$SSH_CONNECTION" ]
then
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa user@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that bashrc is called within ~/.profile appending the ssh connection to the end of the ~/.profile had fixed the problem.